# Can a schema support organizing multiple data entries in a key-index structure rather than a list?

Tags: python, serialization, data-structures, schema

I have a bunch of objects {id: 1, b:32} {id:3, b:43} ...
I want to create a schema for a data structure which will hold them in the following manner:

```
{
   1: {id: 1, b:32},
   3: {id: 3, b:43}
}
```

Basically a table indexed by the 'id' key.
However, looking at schemas enforcing libraries such as, in Python, [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [DRF serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), I can only figure out how to organise them in lists:

```
[
 {id: 1, b:32},
 {id: 3, b:43}
]
```

Is there a hard rule in schema definition theory that prevents me from organizing my data as in the first example?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/483) may help you.

Comment: Seems like just what I need, thank you Mauro! If you write this in a answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It isn't need. You reach the goal! ;-)